# Dagger/Hilt missing binding. Repository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have this interface

```
interface ShowsScheduleRepository {
    suspend fun getShowsSchedule(medium: String, timeSlot: String): ShowsSchedule
}
```

which is provided in this class

```
class GetShowsScheduleUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ShowsScheduleRepository
)
```

by

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideShowsScheduleRepository(api: TDRetrofitApi): ShowsScheduleRepository {
    return ShowsScheduleRepoImpl(api)
}
```

and then this class is injected in a viewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class HomeFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getShowsSchedule: GetShowsScheduleUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
```

And when I am trying to build I get the error that it cannot provide a `ShowsScheduleRepository` without an  @Provides-annotated method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note to self: Put the AppModule file in the same Android Module where the HiltEntryPoint is

Answer (score 1):

The `provideShowsScheduleRepository` method should be placed in a module class (by saying that I mean a class annotated with `@Module`). Are you sure that this module is installed in the correct scope? If not, try adding `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)`. (You can replace `SingletonComponent` with any other component that is described [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components.html) based on your needs)

Comment: Thank you for your time. It wasn't that. I had the AppModule file location in a different library....